# Make a div show a specific message if input is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have a div have the exact same content as an input. If I type "lalala" in the input, I want it to show in the div. That part is working fine. But I would also like to show in the div something along the lines of "the input is empty" when the input, is empty.

So basically like

input = blablabla
div = blablabla

input = 
div = The input is empty

I'm trying to make it "if empty, do this, if not, show the same content as the input". But for some reason, the empty bit is not working.

````
    const textInput = $('#input');
    const textOutput = $('#output');

    if ( textInput.value == "" ) {
        textOutput.innerHTML += 'It's empty';
    } else {
        textInput.on("input", function() {
            textOutput.text($(this).val());
        });
    }



});```
````

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] please. And do you notice anything unusual about your string here `'It's empty'`?

Comment: add \ - 'It\'s empty'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step by step instruction on what needs changing

As you are using jQuery:

- `textInput.value  == ""` should be `! textInput.val()`
- `textOutput.innerHTML = 'it's empty'` should be `textOutput.text("it's empty");`
- `textOutput.text($(this).val());` should be `textOutput.text(textInput.val());`

and it should all be within the `on "input"` listener i.e.

`textInput.on('change',function(){ /*code goes here*/ });`

Comment: Thank you, it really helped!

Answer (score 3):

- You have an unescaped quotation here `'It's empty'`.
- There's no reason to use `innerHTML`
- You should use `===` to compare equality.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input');
const output = document.querySelector('#output');

input.addEventListener('input', () =>
  output.textContent = input.value ? input.value : "It's empty.");
```

```html
<input id="input">

<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: why are you using "document.querySelector" insead of just "$"?

Comment: nice example...!

Comment: @MichaelT because `$` isn't vanilla JS.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the apostrophe ' in your string you are mixing Vanilla Javascript with JQuery and your trigger is inside the if() block which is supposed to be called on the trigger.

Change the code like this:

```
const textInput = $('#input');
const textOutput = $('#output');

textInput.on("input", function() {
    if ( $(this).val() === "" ) {
        textOutput.html('It\'s empty');
    } else {
        textOutput.html($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### fix if

```
if ( textInput.value == "" ) {
    textOutput.innerHTML += 'It\'s empty';
} else {
    textInput.on("input", function() {
        textOutput.text($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Better if:

```
if (!textInput.value) {
  textOutput.innerHTML = 'It\'s empty';
} else {
  textInput.on("input", () => textOutput.text($(this).val()));
}
```

Short:

```
!textInput.value ? textOutput.innerHTML = 'It\'s empty' : textInput.on("input", () => textOutput.text($(this).val()));
```

Answer (score 1):

There ya go

```js
    const $textInput = $('#input');
    const $textOutput = $('#output');
    
    $textInput.on('input', function(){

        if($textInput.val() != '') {
            $textOutput.text($textInput.val());
        }
        else {
            $textOutput.text('It\'s empty');
        }

    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :)
please provide explanation as to what you have done and why. simply supplying the op with a solution without any explanation is generally discouraged.